# Show two ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

When APP is Launching - start SigninView - it's Okey. Next if success - I need showTripController(). Function work but nothing show? What's a problem?

```
func showSigninView() {
    let controller = self.window?.rootViewController!.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DRVAuthorizationViewController")
    self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showTripController() {
    let cv = self.window?.rootViewController!.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DRVTripTableViewController")
    let nc = UINavigationController()
    self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(nc, animated:true, completion: nil)
    nc.pushViewController(cv!, animated: true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must add this before you use window :

```
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Another thing to keep in mind is:

*Sometimes keyWindow may have been replaced by window with nil rootViewController (showing UIAlertViews, UIActionSheets on iPhone, etc), in that case you should use UIView's window property.*

So, instead of using rootViewController, use the top one presented by it:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}

if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
    topController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace last 3 lines of showTripController as below:

```
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cv));
self.window!.rootViewController = nc
```